# pushing and evaluating Stack <double>

Tags: java, stack, double, evaluation, postfix-notation

First time posting so please inform me of how to improve.

I'm working on a program to convert infix notation to postfix and then evaluate.  My conversion to postfix went well, but I'm having some trouble with my evaluation.  In the code below, when I try to convert the operands into a double variable 'number' they don't maintain their value (see runtime output below).  Here is part of the method in question (the print statements are for debugging only).

```
public boolean evaluatePostfix(StringBuffer postfix)
    {
        Stack <Double> operand = new Stack <Double>();//stack to hold operand values
        double answer = 0; //variable to hold result of expression
        boolean error = false; //tests for input error
        int pos = 0; //temp veraible stores position in postfix expression
        double number = 0; //temp variable to convert char to double. also stores that value for reference
        double val1 = 0; //first value for operations
        double val2 = 0; //second value for operations
        double val3 = 0; //answer for val1 and val2

        while (!error && pos < postfix.length())
                {
                    System.out.println(postfix.charAt(pos));
                    if (postfix.charAt(pos) == ' ')
                        ; //do nothing
                    else if (Character.isDigit(postfix.charAt(pos)))
                    {
                        number = Double.parseDouble(postfix.substring(pos));
                        System.out.printf ("number = %f", number);
                        operand.push(number);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        val1 = operand.pop();
                        val2 = operand.pop();
                        System.out.printf ("val1: %f\tval2: %f\n", val1, val2);
```

> ---At runtime--- 1
>
> number = 49.000000
>
> 8
>
> number = 56.000000
>
> +
>
> val1: 56.000000
>
> val2: 49.000000
>
> val3 = 105.000000
>
> 105.0

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it and clicking on the curly brackets `{}`.

Comment: You can use the `{}` button in the editor to format a whole block of text as code, and it'll get displayed nicely with indenting and color coding.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
number = postfix.charAt(pos);
```

with:

```
number = Double.parseDouble(Character.toString(postfix.charAt(pos)));
```

The **[Double.parseDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)** method converts the string in double:

> Returns a new double initialized to the value represented by the
>   specified String, as performed by the valueOf method of class Double.

*(from Javadoc)*

---

If you split the String with postfix.toString.split(" ") and then iterate on the string[] you will be able to parse also double values (like "8.4567"):

```
    String[] sa = postfix.toString().split(" ");        
    for (String string : sa) {
    .... omissis ...
```

otherwise your code will be correct  only parsing single digit integer values.

Comment: I'm not sure why but I'm getting the following error after implimenting your suggestion 
{EquationEvaluator.java:87: error: method parseDouble in class Double cannot be applied to given types; 
number = Double.parseDouble(postfix.charAt(pos)); ^ 
required: String found: char 
reason: actual argument char cannot be converted to String by method invocation conversion
 does the fact that postfix is of type Stringbuffer have anything to do with it?

Comment: You may try to use `Character.toString(postfix.charAt(pos))` to obtain a string from a char.

Comment: That's correct my mistake, I'm going to edit my answer using substring method of StringBuffer which is returning directly a String.

Comment: There's got to be a method to convert a character to a floating point value.  I'm trying to find it right now.  Grateful to anyone who finds it first!

Comment: Thanks tony.  It still doesn't like it.  It fails at runtime now.  it appears to fail trying to convert that first digit to a  double
{Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 7 +"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
        at EquationEvaluator.evaluatePostfix(EquationEvaluator.java:87)
        at Tester.main(Tester.java:29)

Comment: I don't need it to evaluate anything other than single digit integers really

Comment: @TonyRad: Sorry, [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#substring%28int%29) doesn't work this way either: 'The substring begins at the specified index and extends to the end of this sequence.' :)

Comment: +1, right: number = Double.parseDouble(Character.toString(postfix.charAt(pos)));

Comment: Bingo!  thanks Tony and Hanno.  The numbers are printing correctly now.  When Hanno first put that suggestion up there I tried to combine the two ideas but I must've made a mistake.  I copied this one though and it worked.

Comment: (or you could just go the cheap-o way of `"" + postfix.charAt(pos)` - but you didn't get that from me, ok? ;-))

Comment: or the more straightforward: postfix.substring(pos, pos+1) :)

Comment: What? There is more than one way to write code??? I'm baffled... I'll remember these shortcuts thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the ASCII value of each character e.g. '1' => `49` and pushing it on to the stack.

Most likely what you want is to use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read numbers converted from the text you input.

Comment: I did figure that it was the ASCII value.  I don't understand the note about the scanner though.  The method pulls in the 'postfix' string from another method and reads those values.  Is there a function or something that will convert those digits into double before I 'push' them onto my stack?

Comment: I meant using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29 to read a double.

Comment: @HannoBinder Thank you for adding the link. I have changed it to use Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing an expression may not be a trivial task. In more complex cases using a parser generator is the only reasonable approach.

In your case, you might do without one:

- What are your 'tokens'?
- How do you detect the start and end of each token?
- Once you have your tokens extracted from the input, what do you do with each of them?

Your tokens appear to be (decimal) numbers and arithmetic operators. - How can you determine the start and end of each? Whitespaces " " between them may make a sufficient delimiter.

Then you can cleanly parse your tokens one at a time: Use `Double.parseDouble(...)` to parse the numerical tokens and process the operators accordingly.

You may want to have a look at Java's [Tokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) for support in extracting the tokens from the input.